# Passing an managedObjectContext from one ViewController to another ViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiviewcontroller

My current project is a Core Data project in Swift that creates notes. I'm trying to set the managedObjectContext of my `destinationVC` from the `currentVC` in `prepareForSegue` and I am trying to figure out how to do that in Swift.

I've used Apple's "canned code" for setting up a CoreData project in Swift. The CoreData stack is set up in `AppDelegate.swift`.

At present, I created a method to generate dummy notes in the AppDelegate if there are no notes in the managed object context. **That works.**

The initial view when the app opens is a Master-Detail VC set up that displays the objects in my managed object context. **That works.** I can click on a note and it displays on the DetailViewController. This is mostly "canned" code Xcode creates when I started the project.

I created a `UIBarButtonItem` "Add" button on the `MasterViewController`, but I can't figure out how to pass the `MasterVC`'s `managedObjectContext` to the `destinationViewController`. When I click that it segues as it should to the `DetailViewController`.

Here are the properties from my `MasterVC`:

```
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var addNoteViewController:AddNoteViewController? = nil  // I added this
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
```

This is my `prepareForSegue` method in the `MasterViewController`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }

    if segue.identifier == "addNote" {
        println("segue.identifier is addNote")
        // I think I need to add stuff here so the destination VC "sees" the managedObjectContext
    }
}
```

I think I also need to add a property on the `AddNoteVC` that the `MasterVC`'s `prepareForSegue` can set. So how do I do that in Swift?

Comment: Please avoid that kind of titles and keep it concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved:

I added this line of code to the `AddNoteViewController`, nothing in `prepareForSegue` in `MasterViewController.swift`

`let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext`

Comment: That works too, although you might want to look at this article: [Tell, don't ask](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask). In your solution, you're *asking* for the managed object context from within the view controller. A "cleaner" pattern is to *tell* the view controller which context to use. (It probably doesn't matter in this particular case, though.)

Comment: Once I get my GitHub issue w/ storyboard addressed, I'll tinker. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To add a property to your `AddNoteViewController`, just add a `var`:

```
import CoreData

class AddNoteViewController: UIViewController {

    var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext?
```

Then you can set this property in your segue:

```
if segue.identifier == "addNote" {
    println("segue.identifier is addNote")
    // I think I need to add stuff here so the destination VC "sees" the managedObjectContext

    let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! AddNoteViewController
    controller.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Aaron! I just figured it out and I came here to post the answer. I added this to `AddNoteViewController.swift` and it worked.
`let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext`

I'll try your solution and see what that does.

Comment: I tried that your solution and it crashes. The log says `Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.AddNoteViewController' (0x109cac5f0) to 'UINavigationController' (0x10b8d2820).`

Comment: @AdrianB You might be using a different segue type. If that's the case, the destination view controller of the segue will be different. You can use `let controller =  segue.destinationViewController as! AddNoteViewController` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I committed to GitHub and ended up blowing up the storyboard. I think Github made a change w/ a conflict that Xcode doesn't like. #WhackAMole